# Почему были отклонены мои правки к неправильному ответу?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, правки, модераторский-произвол

Я назвал тему: «Мафия или "свои ребята" на ru.stackoverflow», потому что убежден, что здесь есть своя мафия или "свои ребята", для которых многие правила ресурса не писаны.

По-большому счёту сейчас мне всё равно, я уже давно всё понял, но вчера был выдающийся случай, результат которого сподвиг меня создать данную тему.

Вначале предлагаю обратить ваше внимание на данное сообщение и тему в целом:

[Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925451/234502)

Хронология событий:

1. Итак пользователь в своём ответе написал:

   > EDGE не любит calc() , замени его и пропиши секунды анимации в
   >   ручную...

   Вначале я подумал, что данный пользователь просто поторопился с ответом или упустил некоторые моменты, а возможно и ему просто всё равно на качество ответа и он стремится заработать некоторую репутацию.
2. Я оставил комментарий к ответу пользователя, что он своим сообщением вводит в заблуждение других, предложил ему написать пояснение на этот счёт. Вскоре я оставил второй комментарий примерно о том же.

   - Сделаю поправку. Кажется, что при высоком рейтинге, у пользователей, а также у модераторов есть возможность смотреть удалённые комментарии. Поэтому предлагаю сделать это и посмотреть их. Я же к сожалению не могу это сделать и вынужден писать по памяти, так как "свои ребята" включая модератора(ов), уже подтерли мои комментарии.
3. От пользователя пришёл ответ в комментариях, что он своему знакомому писал ответ и ему в "общем-то всё равно, что там в этих браузерах" - примерно так и написал. Он видимо убежден, что "своим" здесь всё можно, например: давать заведомо ложный ответ, а затем пиши, что тебе собственно всё равно, что там вообще такое.

   - Сделаю поправку. В самом первом своём комментарии я указал источник, который подтверждает, что пользователь своим заявлением вводит других в заблуждение, а именно: [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Как видно, на странице данного сайта, что `calc()` никогда не имел никаких проблем в поддержке Edge, более того, он поддерживается в более старых браузерах(IE 10 и IE 11). Кто мало-мальски понимает в вёрстке сайтов, знает, что это за сайт(caniuse.com) и регулярно к нему обращается в работе, увы пользователь не из их числа.
4. Далее был ряд комментариев, после которых пользователь получил мой ответ, что раз он выбирает подобную позицию, значит умышленно готов вводить других пользователей в заблуждение и я свободно отредактирую его сообщение, удалив оттуда заведомую ложь.
5. Я надеялся, что на этом, или вскоре, всё закончится. Понимая свой прошлый опыт, я предполагал, что данный пользователь попытается заняться беспределом и таки будет пытаться сохранить своё столь ценное ему вранье, поскольку иллюзорная корона на голове давно уже образовалась. Мне хочется спросить: корона-то не жмёт?

   Я [отредактировал сообщение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/321818) пользователя, удалив оттуда ложь. Однако, как и ожидалось по опыту ранее, моя правка не прошла модерацию и ложь сохранилась на своём месте.
6. Я был готов, что "свои ребята" помогут кому надо, пусть и помогая в таком гнусном деле, как отстаивание вранья. Но не ожидал всё же, что модератор(ы) состоят в этой же "банде" и помогают кому нужно и когда нужно.

   Нажал на кнопку тревоги и выбрал пункт: привлечь внимание модератора, где описал подробно ситуацию, а также ссылку на caniuse.com. На этом всё, все мои комментарии были подтерты, а ложь пользователя осталась на своём месте, к стыду данного ресурса.

**Заключение**

На этом всё, местная мафия своих не сдаёт, пусть даже и ложь будет написана, пусть это в дальнейшем и может ввести в заблуждение массу людей. Неугодное будет удалено, а то, что необходимо останется. "Своим" будет право вводить в заблуждение других, а у "не своих" даже комментарии будут подтерты, где они пытаются указать на ошибку.

После данного своего сообщения я не жду особенных изменений на данном ресурсе, потому что предполагаю, что в "своих ребятах" состоят все модераторы. Но вдруг если это и не так и найдётся кто-то один, то пусть он изучит представленную здесь информацию и попытается разобраться и навести порядок. Ведь дошло уже до того, что верные правки не утверждаются и комментарии где явно указывают на ошибку, удаляются.

Всегда раньше думал, что если у пользователя высокий рейтинг, то он скорее всего многим помог, но что касается пользователя и его подхода, то про него я думаю: сколько же должно быть вреда он здесь принёс.

Comment: Почему бы вам просто не поставить минус и не написать свой правильный ответ со всеми пруфами? Понимающие люди проголосуют за правильный ответ.

Comment: если подходить дословно: не любит и не поддерживает - не одно и то же, следовательно без пояснений автора текста, что он под этим имел ввиду, нельзя утверждать что была ложь. Однако в любом случае - неверный ответ не противоречит правилам. Таким образом, можно считать, что была попытка вандализации (удаления информации добавленной автором, не противоречащей правилам) вопроса. Вместо этого надо было поставить минус, если ответ неверен, и, в идеале, как указал @АндрейNOP, дать свой правильный ответ.

Comment: кроме того, к сожалению, тревоги не предназначены для _неверных_ ответов.

Comment: Желтушный заголовок тоже убрал. Ни к чему он тут, сбивает с толку.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Какие правки автор сообщения имеет право отклонять, согласно политике сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8453/208074)

Comment: @Kromster `Желтушный заголовок тоже убрал. Ни к чему он тут, сбивает с толку.` - это вы зря, я вам на это разрешение не давал и считаю, что у вас не было на это права. Вы лишили возможности многих пользователей, быстро найти ответ на свой вопрос: почему здесь так происходит.

Comment: Кстати я уже натыкался на неверный ответ Air, как-то он написал, что нельзя использовать несколько footer и header на странице. Я его поправил (прикрепил ссылку к документации), но всё равно он остался при своём мнении. Спорить не стал, но жалко будет, если на сайте будут оставаться неверные ответы.

Comment: А вот что у меня было, там тоже его ответ интересный) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/904149/javascript-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5#comment1484494_904149

Comment: Мне если честно всё равно)) Будет авторы вопросов перепроверяют. А так да, было бы не плохо, если бы "плохие" ответы и комментарии как-то можно было помечать, типо "Сомнительный ответ"

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev Мне не всё равно, в будущем люди, кто будут просматривать подобные "ответы", тем самым могут быть введены в заблуждение и делать ошибки, порой грубые и продолжительные. Мне непонятно, как может быть всё равно, нужно бороться за качество ответов, а не за их наличие само по себе.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev Так для ответов это уже есть, стрелка вниз. А вот то, что в комментариях регулярно пишут неправильные ответы, которые даже нельзя минуснуть, это непорядок, да.

Answer (score 11):

Все гораздо проще.

Правку отменил автор ответа, и он имел на это полное право. Если вы считаете, что ответ неточен или неверен - не стоит его править. Хватит обычного комментария в *нейтральном тоне*, [в рамках принятых на сайте норм поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Чего не стоит делать:

- Не стоит обвинять автора ответа в умышленном введении людей заблуждение. Например, не стоит употреблять фразы вроде "Заявление похоже на какой-то громкий вброс, рассчитанный на незнание слушателей.", не имея на это достаточных оснований.
- Не стоит переходить на личности
- Не стоит советовать автору ответа перестать отвечать :)

Я удалил всю ветку комментариев под ответом, т.к. среди них не нашлось ни одного без проблем, перечисленных выше.

Варианты решения:

- Напишите свой ответ, который будет решать проблему топикастера круче, чем существующий неточный ответ.
- Напишите новый, нейтральный комментарий.
- Ничего не делайте, пусть страдают те, кто, не думая, копипастит решения из заминусованных ответов. Так им и надо.

Comment: Полное право отклонять правки? Так вроде вообще любой с 2K может ревизию откатить. Авторство тут как бы ни при чём. По поводу кописты из заминусованного ответа, это, имхо, сильно сказано. На момент публикации поста на мете у ответа был рейтинг (0/-1) и при этом ответ был принят! Принятый ответ внушает доверие несколько больше, кмк, чем один единственный минус.

Comment: @älёxölüt `Так вроде вообще любой с 2K может ревизию откатить` - да, но конкретно в этом случае правку  отклонил именно автор ответа, как указал PashaPash.

Comment: @älёxölüt вопрос был именно про отклонение правки, а не про откат - "правка не прошла модерацию" - модерации ни в каком виде не было. Просто автор ответа сказал "не, спасибо, так лучше" :). по поводу принятого ответа - см. последний пункт. Каждый копипастящий должен сам оценивать риски. Даже если там один минус. Даже если минусов вообще нет.

Comment: @Arhad я в курсе. Но более общий ответ, имхо, лучше, чем частный. // PashaPash, даже заплюсованный ответ может иметь подводные камни. Но речь не об этом, речь о некоем уравновешивании минуса (а может даже нескольких) и галочки. А если, как упоминал тут ТС, ответ давался какому-то знакомому, то эта галочка вообще несколько сомнительная. Но какой читатель ответа сможет это понять? Странно ещё, что при установке галочки плюса не поставили (а может вместо плюса как раз влепили минус? Хехе).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87567/discussion-on-answer-by-pashapash-------).

Answer (score 10):

Вы же понимаете, что сообщение с подобным обвинительным тоном заведомо будет восприниматься другими участниками негативно?

Даже если Air не прав, такой иронизирующий пост будет встречен не так, как вы рассчитываете.

1. Если Air написал заведомо ложный ответ, то он не прав, т.к. цель отвечающего - не помочь конкретному участнику, а помочь будущим участникам с такой проблемой.
2. Если вы оставили правки, а их зареджектили в очереди, то возможны варианты:

   1. Вы не правы.
   2. Проверяющие в очереди не в теме.
   3. Проверяющий не понял вашего посыла.

[Вашу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/321818) правку отклонил сам Air, как автор ответа. Не понимаю, про какую мафию вообще тогда речь. И, как я понял, на тревогу модераторы пока не ответили. Тогда не ясно, почему вы не дождались их ответа на тревогу.

Вообще, вы в своей правки просто удалили текст из ответа, как я понял, не прокомментировав правку. Если бы я такое увидел в очереди, то, скорей всего, отклонил бы как вандализм или т.п.

Если они вам, всё же, ответили, но вас ответ не устроил, то хорошо бы этот момент уточнить в вопросе. Ну и в таком случае лучше через форму сайта связаться с администрацией, которая вам поможет разобраться в вопросе (¬‿¬ ).

Comment: Комментарий, кстати, к правке есть

Comment: @yolosora вы правы. А я не заметил о_О

Comment: Если комментарии удалены (а они удалены), то значит модераторы так или иначе в курсе ситуации. Ведь ТС сам не удалял свои комментарии.

Comment: @älёxölüt может регуляркой удалилось, например )

Comment: Может и так. Но вряд ли там были спасибо-подобные слова :)

Comment: @älёxölüt, но регулярка удаляет не только спасибо-подобный слова :-) в ней еще много интересных слов :):))

Comment: @Suvitruf Мой тон в порядке. Прочитайте пожалуйста моё сообщение ещё раз. После того, как я оставил свои первые комментарии, пользователь Air сам ответил, что: "он здесь для знакомого писал, методом тыка и ему вообще всё равно, что там в этих браузерах", это почти цитата, можете спросить у модераторов, они подтвердят, что примерно так там и было написано. Возможно это для вас хороший тон. Только после данного ответа я решил править его сообщение, также при правке конечно указал причину. Моя правка не прошла и вскоре все комментарии, где я указывал на ошибку, были затерты.

Answer (score 10):

1. "Не любит" и "не поддерживает" - это не одно и то же. В IE, например, calc как бы полностью поддерживается, но в специфических случаях роняет весь браузер (и это написано именно в тех местах, где роняет, а не в основной статье по `calc`).
2. Удалённые комментарии видят только модераторы, не пользователи. Пользователи с 10К репутации могут видеть только удалённые сообщения, но не комментарии.
3. Сайт модерируется сообществом, подробнее тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges.
4. Правки, меняющие суть ответа не приветствуются. Это чужой ответ и просто так менять его на своё усмотрение нельзя.
5. В данном случае правка была отклонена не из очереди, а самим автором ответа (и ты это видишь ведь по своей ссылке).
6. Все комментарии были удалены модератором одновременно с точностью до секунды, вероятно через пункт "Очистить комментарии". Твоё утверждение про оставшиеся комментарии автора ответа ложно.
7. Тревога модераторам была отклонена поскольку модераторы не должны проверять техническую составляющую. Для этого есть сообщество, комментарии и голоса. Модератор не обязан разбираться во всех представленных на сайте технологиях и знать, в какой версии чего какая проблема есть, а какой нет - он же не бог.
8. А вот снести все комментарии в ответ на твою тревогу - вполне себе реакция - они действительно не очень вежливые.
9. Я восстановил один из комментариев и добавил свой.

Comment: Первый ваш пункт. Приведите пожалуйста пример, где calc() в IE роняет браузер. Вижу я, что вы умышленно или нет, не указываете версию IE. Я же  регулярно использую calc() и вот, в IE-11 не припоминаю проблем. Приведите пожалуйста пример calc() где он роняет браузер в IE-11. Только пример пожалуйста не извращённый, а такой который используется в стандартной работе и который можно объяснить, почему хотелось бы использовать именно его, но невозможно из-за того, что он "роняет весь браузер".

Comment: Восьмой ваш пункт. Вы модератор и видите удалённые комментарии. Пользователь Air сам написал в комментариях, что дал ответ: "методом тыка, для своего знакомого и он вообще не в курсе, что там в этих браузерах" - это почти цитата, я помню что там было написано. После этого я решил править его сообщение. Но конечно же это не послужило поводом для вас, для редактирования или удаления вопроса, ведь это невозможно. А в моих же комментариях было нечто очень невежливое и возмутительное, явно что-то такое, что даёт полное право легко и просто удалить их.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov модераторы не следят за контентом. Если вопрос неправильный, то они не могут его удалить/поправить.

Comment: @Suvitruf  ^^ Удивительный комментарий. Модератор легко удалил сразу все мои комментарии, где я верно указывал на ошибку. Но при этом модераторы `не могут его удалить/поправить`. Вы сами не видите здесь двойные стандарты? Модератор без проблем затёр все мои комментарии и я не думаю, что он долго колебался или затем сожалел о том.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov ну да, если они посчитали это шумом, то да. Я писал про ответ. Они не могут ничего сделать с ответом, если он неправильный. Могут только, если он нарушает правила.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87565/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy-------).

Answer (score 7):

Выскажусь и я. Коль тут холивар решили развести в праздники.

Как написали красиво в чате:

> *Как без драмы в Новый год.*

Пройдемся по пунктам:

1. Конечно, внесение заведомо ложных ответов не приветствуется и это явно не то, что ждут пользователи заходя на данный ресурс.
2. Данный пост был написан явно с определенной агрессией в отношении многих людей на данном ресурсе и вот это тоже не правильно. Автор, вы что, знаете всех лично?

   Так, что тут и вы немного перегнули палку и не правы. Прочитав этот пост, я хоть и к тов. Air не имею никакого отношения, принял и на свою сторону, а так получается, что вы можете оскорбить большую часть сообщества, своим гневом в отдельной ситуации. Думайте над тем что пишите.
3. Ваше мнение, это ваше мнение и если вы классный эксперт в этой области, конечно же сообщество к вам прислушается.
4. Мафия!!! - что за бред? Вы с какой планеты (или страны)? Возможно, некоторые пользователи и могут симпатизировать другим, тем или иным способом, но так как вы пишите, это прям сговор на межгосударственном уровне. Джеймсы Бонды и Исаевы отдыхают, против вашего расследования. Если уж кидаете такое столь грозное заявление, то предоставьте факты, а не просто отдельно взятый пост, который вас лично всбесил (очень странно, что только вас).
5. Ресурс не идеален (и перфекционистам тут сложно, тут я вас немного понимаю), он до сих пор в процессе становления, тут просто...C'est La Vie...
6. Возвращаясь к самому ответу, хочу добавить, что сообщество так и работает, что неправильные ответы в процессе отфильтровуются, получая негативные оценки, если уж на то пошло - просто поставьте минус, ваша репутация позволяет. В чем же тут проблема? Ваш минус никто не заберет.
7. Так как вы хороший специалист в данной области и разбираетесь в вопросе лучше, напишите правильный ответ. Что ж тут сложного? Все так и поступают. Хороший ответ в результате получит максимальную оценку, так как оценивается он всем русскоязычным сообществом (а это тысячи человек), а не отдельно взятые люди.

Я надеюсь, что мой взгляд на ситуацию хоть чем-то будет полезен. Извиняюсь, если я вызвал у вас какие-то эмоции (позитивные или негативные), в качестве цели преследовал иное. Хорошего вам настроения и позитивного настроя :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87566/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-spirin-------).