# Какие правки автор сообщения имеет право отклонять, согласно политике сайта?

Tags: обсуждение, правки

В смежном треде увидел такое высказывание про предлагаемую правку:

> Правку отменил автор ответа, и он имел на это полное право.

Технически, автор сообщения, как и модератор, может единолично принимать/отклонять предложенные правки. Отклонённые на данном этапе правки не попадают в ревизию сообщения вовсе. Но в других ситуациях, любой участник с 2К репы может собственноручно вносить правки в любое незаблокированное сообщение, а также откатывать ревизии. В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос:

> Имеет ли автор сообщения больше прав (с точки зрения политики сайта) на изменение/отклонение правок других участников в своём собственном сообщении, чем другие участники с [привилегией редактирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)?

Если да, то какого рода должны быть эти правки. Если нет, то почему?

Речь именно о позволительности со стороны правил пользования сайтом (может даже пока и негласным, но в таком случае их нужно будет по итогам обсуждения закрепить в справке), а не технических возможностях. Например, можно заменить всё сообщение точками, но это будет скорее всего воспринято как вандализм, особенно, если это сообщение чужое, особенно, если это был вопрос, имеющий ответы, или чей-то заплюсованный ответ. Но если в сообщении имеется какой-то лютый треш, вызывающий кровь из глаз, то замена на точки будет воспринята сообществом вполне позитивно. Хотя, конечно, в этом случае надо как минимум использовать тревогу, например, для призыва модератора.

Comment: Откатывать и вносить правки могут все у кого есть на это права (репа, авторство или админство). Уточните, ваш вопрос к существующим механикам сайта, или к идеальным?

Comment: На всякий случай - под полным правом подразумевалось "единолично принять решение по правке". Право сделать что-то в один клик - это тоже право :)

Comment: @Kromster речь о политике, а не о механике. Это есть как в заголовке, так и в тексте. Хотя, конечно, принятая политика должна быть отражена в механике. Но тогда получается вообще нельзя делать различий между технической возможностью и некими правилами. Например, я могу создать клона и голосовать за свои сообщения (технически), но сайт это запрещает по правилам.

Comment: Уточните этот момент в вопросе плиз. Сейчас он неясен как минимум 3 людям (мне +2 на комментарии).

Comment: @Kromster это всё ваши боты :) но, так и быть, сейчас внесу правки. Ведь я имею на это право как автор!

Comment: @Kromster дописал вопрос, но как-то так получилось, что звучит как часть ответа.

Answer (score 6):

У автора сообщения есть исключительное право определения того, что он имел в виду в своём сообщении. Иными словами, правку, которая искажает смысл сообщения, может откатить любой участник - но только за автором последнее слово в определении того, искажает ли правка смысл сообщения или нет.

Answer (score 3):

Отклонить то он может что угодно. Вопрос только в том, как на это отреагирует сообщество.

После публикации ваши сообщения принадлежат сообществу и нельзя просто так отклонять правки, только потому что автору так хочется. И если автор отклоняет правки, улучшающие сообщение, то это вандализм.

По сабжу же, "Какие правки автор сообщения имеет право отклонять, согласно политике сайта?":

1. Несущественные правки (?!).
2. Вандализм.
3. Правки, которые меняют смысл сообщения.
4. Правки, которые правят код/семантику/логику. Вместо правки, по хорошему, автор правки должен предложить свой ответ.

Comment: Сабж всё же не только в сабже (заголовке). А в тексте поста: "Имеет ли автор сообщения больше прав...". Реакция сообщества - по сути и определяется политикой, если политика сайта не подходит участнику, он покидает такой сайт. Имеются конкретные случаи, и мы о них знаем.

Comment: @älёxölüt а разве не реакция первичная, а не политика?

Comment: Если реакция большинства расходится с политикой партии, то это очень серьёзный звоночек.

Comment: @älёxölüt ну, партия в дела модерации контента особо не вмешивается вроде. Если только дело не касается кок оф кондукта.

Comment: Ответ ваш неверен. Но я не лезу его исправлять. Потому что на Stack Overflow допустимы только правки ответов, которые согласуются с мнением автора. Вы можете поставить минус ответу, который считаете неверным, можете в комментарии указать в чём он неверен, можете свой "верный" ответ опубликовать, но изменять ответ, чтобы он стал "верным" вы не должны, если автор ответа против.

Comment: @jfs твоё мнение невернее моего © jfs.

Comment: @Suvitruf не нужно мне приписывать ваши фантазии.

Comment: Help Center -> Our Model: When should I edit posts? -> "To clarify the meaning of the post (**without changing that meaning**)" (выделение моё)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, автор имеет больше прав, как минимум до тех пор, пока сообщение не помечено общим. На общее сообщение все имеют равные права. Хотя, можно отдельно рассмотреть ответы на общие вопросы - в некоторых случаях стоит относиться к ответам в них как к авторским (впрочем, это скорее к enSO, чем к нам).

Насколько больше - тут уже надо смотреть по ситуации. Автор заложил в сообщение какую-то идею и только он может (но не всегда, вспоминаем пример про точки) передумать и её поменять.

Правки других участников должны оставаться в рамках заложенной в сообщение идеи.

Comment: Например, я знаю одного участника, который принципиально не использует заглавные буквы в сообщениях. Допустим, кто-то внёс правку, устраняющую этот изъян, и, допустим, автор отклонил такую правку. У автора по-прежнему больше прав чем у редактора?

Comment: @älёxölüt, ну если отклонил, то да. Но по идее не должен отклонять.

Comment: К сожалению, не могу с этим согласиться. Я считаю, что автор не имеет морального права отклонять правки, улучшающие сообщение, а грамотная орфография - это безусловно улучшение. Отклонение таких правок должно рассматриваться как вандализм.

Comment: @älёxölüt, заглавность букв - это не орфография...

Comment: Серьёзно? А что же тогда это?

Comment: Какая разница что это? Правки, которые улучшают сообщение отклонять нельзя. Это вандализм.

Comment: @älёxölüt, вроде бы [грамматика](http://eoru.ru/gram/14). Но можно сходить на РЯ и уточнить.

Comment: Можно и [сходить](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/17298/183872).

Comment: @älёxölüt, там про заглавные буквы ничего не сказано.

Comment: @Suvitruf вы заблуждаетесь. Под вашим ответом подробнее изложил почему.